# Limit of a sum 1: $\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=1}^n\sqrt{n^4+k} \cdot \sin \frac{2k\pi }{n}$

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=1}^n\sqrt{n^4+k} \cdot \sin \frac{2k\pi }{n}$$

It looks like a Riemann sum, but I don't know how to approach it. Any hint would be appreciated. (Without Taylor expansion)

EDIT: The answer is $- \frac{1}{4 \pi}$

Comment: You shouldn't have accepted the answer yet, I believe -- it is currently not complete.

Comment: @ClementC. I understood the concept, thank you, but I'll leave it like this till it's finished then.

Answer (score 3):

*I don't have time to finish right now; I'll leave this as Community Answer, so that anyone can feel free to edit it; if no one does, I'll get back to it later.*

The inhomogeneity between $n^4$ and $k$ will a priori prevent you from seeing this as a Riemann sum: since there is no way to massage $\sqrt{n^4+k}$ in order to make a factor $\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}$ appear.

However, what you *can* do is "guess and then use inequalities and the squeeze theorem to prove the guess was right." I know you do not want to use Taylor expansions, so I will not (but it's hidden in the "guess" part).

First, rewrite
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^4+k}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}
= n^3 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}
$$

- **Guess part**: Now, we are going to use the fact that 
  $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}+1} = \frac{1}{2}\tag{i}$$, so we expect $\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}-1$ to "behave like $\frac{k}{2n^4}$" and (ii) $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x)\, dx = 0 \tag{ii}$$
  (Riemann sum).

  Combining the two, it is "reasonable" to expect that
  $$\begin{align}
  n^3 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}
  &= 
  n^3 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^4}}-1\right)\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} + n^3\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} \\
  &\approx
  n^3 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2n^4}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} + n^3\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} \\
  &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} + n^3\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n} \\
  &\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x\sin(2\pi x)\, dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x)\, dx =  \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x\sin(2\pi x)\, dx \\&= \boxed{-\frac{1}{4\pi}}
  \end{align}$$
  This is our (very handwavy) guess; let us prove it.
- **Proving the guess:**

Comment: @DHMO There was no L''Hopital in (i). As mentioned in the text you removed, it was literally, by definition, the derivative at $0$ of the function $f(x) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sqrt{1+x}$: $f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$.

Comment: I see. Feel free to put the text back in then.

Comment: Bah, the new proof works as well. I just felt compelled to mention it, as someone who loathes using L'Hopital.